# Moving an image when the user moves the finger over document

Tags: javascript, android, css, touch-event

I want to move an image in mobile devices on touch, like when ever user moves the finger over page, image keep moving and always stay at the user finger position, something like web cursor, i am using this code:

```
 document.addEventListener('touchmove', this.onMouseMove);
 document.addEventListener('touchStart', this.onMouseMove);
 document.addEventListener('touchEnd', this.onMouseMove);
```

and

```
onMouseMove = (e) => {
   const img = document.getElementById('drawing-mouse-pointer');
   img.style.left = `${e.touches[0].clientX}px`;
   img.style.top = `${e.touches[0].clientY }px`;
   console.log(e.touches[0] && e.touches[0].clientY);
}
```

but the image only move once when user click and then stops. how can i keep moving the image with touch.

Comment: I think you only need to bind to touchmove, try removing the listeners for start and end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally I would recommend using a library for this like [Interact.js](http://interactjs.io/), so instead of what you did, you could do the following:

```
interact('.draggable')
  .draggable({
  // enable inertial throwing
  inertia: true,
  // keep the element within the area of it's parent
  restrict: {
    restriction: "parent",
    endOnly: true,
    elementRect: { top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 1, right: 1 }
  },
  // enable autoScroll
  autoScroll: true
});
```

Where draggable is the classname of the object you want to move. Also, I want to note that in your code, you were attaching event listeners to the document like so `document.addEventListener('touchmove', this.onMouseMove);` This adds the event listener to the document, not any particular object, so it wouldn't really help you move individual elements. If you want to attach an event to a specific element, you need to reference that element like so:

```
let el = document.getElementById('my-el');
el.addEventListener('touchmove', onMouseMove);
```